# does the spread method work on objects? How do you copy an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        lists: [], 
        items: {}  
    };
}
```

So `this.state.items` is an object.

Now I have:

```
handleAddItem(s) {
    var key = Object.keys(s)[0];
    var value = s[key];

    var allItems = {...this.state.items};
    allItems[key].push({name: value});

    console.log(allItems);
    console.log(this.state.items);
}
```

this.state.items is initially null just {} and s is an object with a key value pair of name: snoopy

```
var s={};
   s[this.props.idName] = this.refs.id.value;
```

Why in the `console.log` are both the same?

Comment: What is the value of `s`? What would you expect to be the result of `{...this.state.items}`?

Comment: s is an object, key/value pair

Comment: no, it works fine

Comment: @DCR Yes that is obvious from your code. But what *exactly* is its value? It influences `key`/`value` and thus `allItems`. How are we supposed to answer when we don't know what you pass to that function?

Comment: it's just:  name: snoopy

Comment: We cannot possibly know why unless you provide the exact values of `state.items` and `s`. Please add them to your question.

Comment: Convert your object to string by using tostring. Again convert it by json.parse. it will create a fully new object as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread syntax does work on the object. However Spread syntax effectively goes one level deep while copying an array. Hence `allItems[key]` would still reference the same object causing it to be mutated when you mutate `allItems[key]`.

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

> Note: Spread syntax effectively goes one level deep while copying an
>   array. Therefore, it may be unsuitable for copying multidimensional
>   arrays as the following example shows (it's the same with
>   Object.assign() and spread syntax).
>
> ```
> var a = [[1], [2], [3]];
> var b = [...a];
> b.shift().shift(); // 1
> // Now array a is affected as well: [[], [2], [3]]
> ```

In case you wish to clone nested state, you would do

```
var allItems = {
    ...this.state.items, 
    [key]: [...this.state.items[key]]
};
```

```js
var items = {
   x: ['a']
};
var value="abc"
var key='x'
var allItems = {
    ...items, 
    [key]: [...items[key]]
};
console.log(allItems, 'before');

allItems[key].push({name: value});
console.log(allItems);
console.log(items);
```

Comment: then how do you copy an object?

Comment: You are copying an object, just not a nested one. For a nested object, you would repeat the steps of spread syntax, or better use ImmutableJS

Comment: then why is console.log the same

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri The question is about [*Object* Rest/Spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), not on an array.

Comment: @str, you would push to an array and my answer just explain that nested objects/arrays are not cloned by spread syntax, it just does a one level deep clone

Comment: your answer doesn't help, sorry but this is so confusing.  How do you copy an object and not mutate the original

Comment: thanks, so in my example is it ok to do what I did or should I make a copy?

Comment: @DCR, if you are setting a state at later point of time, you would still do the same, since setState overrides the state mutation. You could check this answer on updating a nested state, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-set-a-nested-state-in-react/43041334#43041334 . I hope I could explain the answer to you

Answer (score 0):

Spread works on objects.

Check the docs at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for more info.
The results are the same because what spread does is copy references, so if you change any value (arrays, objects) it reflects on the original.

By using spread you're basically making a shallow copy not a deep copy, so the inner values remain intact.